# Can a/some DBMS be installed as an OS

Tags: dbms

Is there any DBMS that can be installed as an OS instead of as an app on a OS?
I wasn't able to find any.

Later edit, just to clarify:
I'm used to installing a DBMS (MySQL, MSSQL) as a server(ice) onto an OS(Windows, Ubuntu, etc.). I was trying to find out if there are some DBMS' that do NOT require an underlying OS and are 'installed' as the OS directly on hardware. I was asking here because googling didn't help.
Thanks for the answers I got, it seems that the answer is close to 'NO'

Comment: Unless you can narrow this question down a *lot*, it'll likely be [closed since it is a shopping list style question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).  Questions about which tool, library, product or resource you should use are off-topic here because they quickly become obsolete and often are just about the preferences of the answerer. If you have an issue with or a question about a specific tool, please revise your question to conform to that scope.

Comment: Over 20 years ago, I was asked to develop an application that used Novell Netware like a database. It wasn't a particularly good idea.

Comment: I disagree that it's a shopping list question. I think it should be reworded to something more concrete. Ask if any database currently runs it's back end in kernel space (ring0). That's much more concrete.

Comment: Maybe you should look at filesystems as a database rather than an OS as a db? Oracle has (had?) RAW tablespaces (not a good idea).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. [IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/power/os/ibm-i), formerly known as AS/400, is a platform with the operating system that has a relational DBMS as its [integral part](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1027715). Indeed, Db2 for i is in a way an alternative access method to the IBM i file system.

Answer (score 3):

Googling a bit I found another operating system called TabulaROSA.

Designed by MIT it works on **32k core supercomputers**, if you or your company can afford  a system like that, it could be a good option.

[image]
<sub>Many overlaps between database systems and the functions required for an OS on a cluster, In the case of TabulaROSA, however, **the functions are managed within database tables instead**.</sub>

Quoted from the article:

> The team defines key OS functions in terms of “rigorous mathematical
>   semantics (associative array algebra) that are directly translatable
>   into database operations. Because the math of database table
>   operations are based on a linear system over the union and
>   intersection semiring, these operations possess a number of
>   mathematical properties that are ideal for parallel operating systems
>   by guaranteeing correctness over a wide range of parallel operations.

> Simulations of forking in TabularROSA are performed by using an
>   associative array implementation and are compared to Linux on a
>   **32,000+ core supercomputer**. Using over 262,000 forkers managing over
>   **68,000,000,000 processes**, the simulations show that TabulaROSA has the
>   potential to perform operating system functions on a massively
>   parallel scale. The TabulaROSA simulations show **20x higher performance
>   compared to Linux**, while managing 2000x more processes in fully
>   searchable tables

You can get more information about it on:

- [REPLACING LINUX WITH A DATABASE SYSTEM](https://www.nextplatform.com/2018/07/23/replacing-linux-with-a-database-system/)

or in this PDF paper:

- [TabulaROSA: Tabular Operating System Architecture for Massively Parallel Heterogeneous Compute Engines](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.05308.pdf)

Comment: Interesting reading, but it doesn't look like a true operating system that you can install, and there isn't much of a database there either; they simply simulated one of the Unix syscalls by multiplying some hash tables.